# Why in-viewport javascript not work in my code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Why `in-viewport` javascript not work in my code ?

https://jsfiddle.net/vncxfx0s/30/

When click on `Click to move` cat image will slide it's ok.

But when i fill code

```
    if($("#testtest").is(":in-viewport"))
    {
        alert("hhh");
    }
```

to detect when `id="testtest"` show in viewport it's will should be alert.

But it's not work anything, how can i do ?

```
    <div style="cursor: pointer;" id="move-left" onclick="left_fn(-422)">
        Click to move
    </div>


    <div style=" width: 500px; overflow: hidden; ">
        <ul style=" width: 2000em; transition: transform 200ms ease-in-out; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); margin-left: -10px; padding: 0;" id="cat-ul">
            <li style=" display: inline-table; ">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/w3abdeV.jpg">
            </li>
            <li style=" display: inline-table; ">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/w3abdeV.jpg">
            </li>
            <li style=" display: inline-table; ">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/w3abdeV.jpg">
            </li>
            <li style=" display: inline-table; ">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/w3abdeV.jpg">
            </li>
            <li style=" display: inline-table; ">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/w3abdeV.jpg">
            </li>
            <li style=" display: inline-table; ">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/w3abdeV.jpg">
            </li>
            <li style=" display: inline-table; ">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/w3abdeV.jpg">
            </li>
            <li style=" display: inline-table; ">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/w3abdeV.jpg">
            </li>
            <li style=" display: inline-table; ">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/w3abdeV.jpg">
            </li>
            <li style=" display: inline-table; ">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/w3abdeV.jpg">
            </li>
            <li id="testtest" style="width: 1px; display: inline-table;">
            </li>            
        </ul>
    </div>

<script>
function left_fn(value) {
    if($("#testtest").is(":in-viewport"))
    {
        alert("hhh");
    }
    document.getElementById("cat-ul").style.transform = "translate3d("+value+"px, 0px, 0px)";
    var x = (value + 422);
    var y = (value - 422);
    document.getElementById('move-left').setAttribute('onclick','left_fn('+y+')')
}
</script>
```

Comment: iti s working [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/vncxfx0s/32/). Probably you have not included jquery library

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to have jquery enabled for that https://jsfiddle.net/vncxfx0s/31/

```
  <script>
function left_fn(value) {
    if($("#testtest").is(":in-viewport"))
    {
        alert("hhh");
    }
    document.getElementById("cat-ul").style.transform = "translate3d("+value+"px, 0px, 0px)";
    var x = (value + 422);
    var y = (value - 422);
    document.getElementById('move-left').setAttribute('onclick','left_fn('+y+')')
}
</script>
```

Comment: what is difference between my code and your code, i don't see anything difference. But why your code is work ?

Comment: i added jquery in the javascript options,check the versions

Comment: you mean External Resources ?

Comment: How can i check version ?

Comment: click on the javascript icon on fiddle,and select jquery framework ,all compatible versions are listed there,and you can tick my answer as accepted if it helps you,below the upvote-downvote link

Comment: Where is  javascript icon on fiddle ? i don't see.